# What is the default unicode character encoding used in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, unicode, encoding, windows-runtime

What is the default unicode character encoding used in Windows? Specifically in Windows Programming (Win32 and WinRT). When I programmed in WinAPI, "char" maps to a 1 byte character storage and "wchar_t" maps to a 2 byte character storage. If UTF-16 encodes all the characters beyond 65536 in 4 bytes then how do Windows map these characters in a "wchar_t" data type? I know that my question is not clear enough but I hope you understand some of my concerns. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows uses [UTF-16LE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-16) for all things Unicode (except for `MultiByteToWideChar()` and `WideCharToMultiByte()`, which support UTF-7, UTF-8, and UTF-16, amongst other charsets installed in the OS).  UTF-16 uses [**surrogate pairs**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-16#Code_points_U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF) (2 16bit values working together) to encode Unicode values above 0xFFFF.  For example, Unicode codepoint U+1D11E is encoded as `0xD834 0xDD1E` (bytes `0x34 0xD8 0x1E 0xDD`) in UTF-16LE.

Comment: thank you for that enlightening response @Remy. But I am still confused why my program in linux(ubuntu 13.04) was able to use "char" data type to hold a unicode character [char* cp = "ӐҖ"; printf("%s\n",cp);] but when I use the same program in windows it wont work, it says that codepage I'm using is wrong. Do you have an idea why this is going on?

Comment: Windows uses the processor's endian-ness.

Comment: @papspi Linux generally uses UTF-8, where codepoints are encoded using a sequence of single byte characters with varying length (between 1 and 6). Consequently, a `char*` can point to storage that is either ASCII encoded or UTF-8 encoded (of which ASCII is a subset). This is a feature of UTF-8 encoding; UTF-16 doesn't expose this feature.

Comment: @Iinspectable: officially, UTF-8 is limited to 1-4 encoded bytes per codepoint, to maintain compatibility with UTF-16. Higher values are illegal. See [RFC 3629](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629).

Comment: @papspi: Many OSes use UTF-16, but Linux is not one of them. If you need to write portable code, you have to take OS differences into account, or else use a portable library, like iconv or ICU, or even the new Unicode features introduced in C++11.